# How to connect to MS SQL Server 2008 via Airflow Connection?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, airflow

I am trying to connect MS SQL Server 2008 in Airflow Connection and I am getting the following error:

> (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (server_name)\n')"

However, the connection works through the DBeaver DBMS. Has anyone encountered a similar error? As an assumption that the problem is related to the drivers, because MS SQL Server 2008 is used and  the following driver to connect:

```
Microsoft JDBC Driver 9.2 for SQL Server 9.2.0.0
```

Is it possible to install that driver via extra parameter in the Airflow Connection?

Comment: Nothing newer than Microsoft JDBC 7.2 for SQL Server actually supports SQL Server 2008, or JDBC 8.4 for SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 is 14 years old and reached [End of Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/general/end-support-sql-server-2008) in 2019. Do you *really* have such an old database? If so, the problem is bigger than just drivers. The [old JDBC drivers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/release-notes-for-the-jdbc-driver) are still available for download anyway

Comment: End of support means that there will be no more fixes, even security fixes, without explicitly paying Microsoft through support incidents. No drivers, no patches. Even the online docs may disappear. If something goes wrong, you're on your own

Comment: I have never heard of integrating SQL Server and Airflow, but I just Googled it and found the link below. Hope it helps.

https://hevodata.com/learn/airflow-sql-server/

Answer (score 0):

Try to install [the Microsoft ODBC driver for SQL Server (Linux)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016).

Works on ubuntu 20.04, airflow 2.4.1.